# Указание путь до logging.properties через VM Options

Tags: java, логирование

-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

Добрый день, если я добавляю logging.properties в корень проекта и прописываю в VM Options строчку :
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

Он подхватывает параметры логгера.

А как сделать так, что-бы была возможность указать путь до logging.properties, который допустим лежит в 
"корень проекта"\src\main\resources

пытался указать -Djava.util.logging.config.file=\src\main\resources\logging.properties

не получилось )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался...

-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/src/main/resources/logging.properties

вот так....